# Uploaded file is not sent successfully using Angular js and springMVC

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angularjs-directive, multipartform-data

I am uploading file using angularjs and springMVC. ng-model wont read file input for that I created a custom directive but still there is no luck. I am not getting any error. MultipartHttpServletRequest is showing empty for file content. Here I am suspecting one thing, My custom directive is not displaying alert which I kept. I need some good help in this, Thanks in advance

### Angularjs code

### 1. this is my custom directive code part

```
angular.module('directory', []).
```

directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {

```
alert("this is directive");
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

}]);

### 2. File input element

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
```

### 3. Ajax call function to upload file

```
 $scope.uploadDocs = function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', $scope.myFile);        
    $http.post("../uploadDocs", fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
        alert("succes");
    })
    .error(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
}
```

4.Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadDocs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String createIncidentTicket(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartHttpServletRequest) {

    return "File is uploaded successfully";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to display  `{{myFile}}` in your template ? 
If your directive works, it should display the file you selected.
(Else check your imports... the directive file may not be added in your index.html)